# Selectively trigger redirect

Tags: ember.js, url-routing

This is a part of my router:

```
this.resource('nodes', function () {

    this.resource('allNodes', function () {
        this.route('index');
        this.route('new');
        this.route('show',   { path: '/:node_id/show' });
        this.route('edit',   { path: '/:node_id/edit' });
        this.route('delete', { path: '/:node_id/delete' });
    });

    this.resource('services', function () {
        this.route('index');
        this.route('new');
        this.route('show',   { path: '/:service_id/show' });
        this.route('edit',   { path: '/:service_id/edit' });
        this.route('delete', { path: '/:service_id/delete' });
    });
...
```

In the `/nodes` route I do a redirect to `allNodes.index`:

```
SettingsApp.NodesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        console.log('NodesRoute.redirect > redirecting to %s', ROUTES.ALL_NODES);
        this.transitionTo(ROUTES.ALL_NODES);
    }
});
```

Now in some other part of my application I am linking to a service directly with the url:

```
#/nodes/services/71ae38cde8584dc9c4eea25e74e68310/show
```

But this is not working, since the redirect of `/nodes` is kicking in. How can I prevent this?

The redirect must be active *only* when going to `/nodes`, not any sub-url. Must I implement this filtering by hand by checking the `currentPath` before redirecting, or is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your redirection in `NodesIndexRoute`.

```
 App.NodesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   beforeModel: function () {
    this.transitionTo('allnodes');
   }
 });
```

[Working Model](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/NN7tk/1/)

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thanks! (sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement it by hand (the information is provided in the hook though)

Addiitionally `redirect` is a deprecated hook, in favor of the `afterModel` hook.

```
SettingsApp.NodesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(resolvedModel, transition){
     if(transition.targetName == 'nodes'){
        this.transitionTo(ROUTES.ALL_NODES);
     }
  }
});
```